# How to detect which user clicked the link MVC3 membership

Tags: database, string, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda

When user clicks the link this method takes the user id and other data and writes it to the database. I can't seem to find a way to track what is the user id since the id is automatically generated.

I am using membership base separately from my base. In order to find userID I was trying to compare UserName strings. **I get this error: "An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request." Also "Cannot create an abstract class."**
Is there a better way to compare two strings form the two databases? Or is there a better way? This is my first time using lambda expressions.

I tried using Single() and First() instead of Where(), but I still get the same error.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToList(Review review, int id, HttpContextBase context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //User user = new User();
                //user.UserID = db.Users.Where(c => c.UserName == context.User.Identity.Name);
                User user = new User();
                Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
                review.MovieID = movie.MovieID;

                string username = context.User.Identity.Name;
                user = (User)db.Users.Where(p => p.UserName.Equals(username));

                review.UserID = user.UserID;
                db.Reviews.Add(review);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
             };

        }
        catch (DataException)
        { 
            //Log the error (add a variable name after DataException)
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View(review);
    }
```

Comment: What userId are you looking to get? The Aspnetmembership user GUID id from the db or is this a custom user base?

Comment: I am trying to get userid from my base based on username which is in the aspnet membership base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're problem is likely this line:

```
user = (User)db.Users.Where(p => p.UserName.Equals(username));
```

the `Where()` extension method returns an IEnumerable, not a single instance, so your implicit cast will fail every time.  what you're looking for is either `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`.  `First()` will throw an exception if there is no match though, while `FirstOrDefault()`will return a null if no match is found.  the line should be :

```
user = db.Users.First(p => p.UserName.Equals(username));
```

you probably have bigger problems than that, but this is the cause of your current error.

### EDIT

upon further looking at your code, you're asking for a HttpContextBase in your action result call.  you never use it, and it's probably the cause of the `Cannot create an abstract class` exception.  remove that parameter and see if you get any different results.

Comment: `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` will work as well, but only if you are expecting there to be only one possible match.